# Include null values using JPQL order by

Tags: java, jpql

I'm developing a lazy loading model for a Java EE project. I've a problem when i try to sort my data which have a null values. For example,

> SELECT u FROM Users u ORDER BY u.Countries.**label** ASC

This query show all the data sorted by Countries but the Users with out a Country are omitted. The matter is here :

1. i need to show them also.
2. I'm implementing a generic model = i don't want to enforce the queries.

> SELECT u FROM Users u ORDER BY u.Countries ASC

This is also are not working, because i must specify a valid ORDER BY item like **label**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an outer join,

```
SELECT t1 FROM Table1 t1 left join t1.column1 c1 ORDER BY c1.id ASC
OR    
SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY Countries DESC NULLS LAST;
```

If you are using criteria API , you can use following

```
USer user = criteriaBuilder.asc(myExpression).nullsFirst();
```

Comment: When i wrote : SELECT u FROM Users u LEFT JOIN u.Countries c ORDER BY c.label ASC ; It returns the expected result. The new question is how to force the LEFT JOIN by default and enhance  my model.

Comment: Not possible with JPQL

Comment: In this case, what is the alternative solution ?